# When I hover over my nav menu it pushes content down, why? How do i change color of li when hover over?

Tags: html, css

When i hover over the navmenu it pushes other content down on the webpage. In addition, when you hover over the nav the font is no longer in white. I'm sorry I am new at programming and borrowed some of this code so it may be sloppy. Thanks

**Here is my html:**

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="http://www.themusicshop.com/default.aspx">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.themusicshop.com/t-store.aspx">Shop Online</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.themusicshop.com/aeRntplan.aspx">Online Rentals</a>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://www.themusicshop.com/aeRntplan.aspx">Rent Now</a></li>
                    <b>Current Rental Customers</b>
                    <li><a href="http://www.themusicshop.com/return.aspx">Rental Returns</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.themusicshop.com/rentalrepair.aspx">Rental Repairs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.themusicshop.com/exchange.aspx">Rental Exchanges</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.themusicshop.com/plessons.asp">Lessons</a>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://www.themusicshop.com/plessons.asp">Private Lessons</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.themusicshop.com/dw-instructors.aspx">Meet the Teachers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.themusicshop.com/request.asp">Request a Lesson</a></li>
                 </ul>
             </div>
         </li> 
               
        <li><a href="http://www.themusicshop.com/lessonmain.asp">Performing Arts Center</a>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://www.themusicshop.com/summer2008.asp">Musical Theater</a></li>
                  <li><a href="http://www.kindermusik.com/kids-music-classes/class-locations/07005/usa/yyyy/1/">Kindermusik</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.themusicshop.com/recording.asp">Recording Studio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.themusicshop.com/ensembles.asp">Group Ensembles</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.themusicshop.com/repairs.asp">Repairs</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.themusicshop.com/signin.aspx">My Account</a></li>
       
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Here is my css:**

```
/* main menu styles */
#nav,#nav ul {
font-family: verdana;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: fixed;
}
#nav {
height: 50px;
left: 0;
overflow: hidden;
top: 0;
position: relative;
}
#nav li {
float:left;
position:relative;
z-index:10;
}
#nav li a {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
color: #fff;
display: inline;
float: left;
font-size: 14px;
height: 51px;
line-height: 40px;
padding: 0 10px;
position: relative;
text-decoration: none;
z-index: 20;
background-color: #005E20;
}
#nav li:first-child a {
background:url(file:///Macintosh%20HD/Users/davidscott/Downloads/example91/images/bg-menu.png) no-repeat left top;
padding-left:35px;
}
#nav li ul li:first-child a {
background-image:none;
padding-left:10px;
}
#nav li.pad {
background: url(file:///Macintosh%20HD/Users/davidscott/Downloads/example91/images/bg-   menu.png) no-repeat right top;
display: inline;
height: 51px;
width: 35px;
}
#nav ul {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
height: auto;
padding: 10px 0;
position: absolute;
top: -115px;
width: 180px;
z-index: 1;
border-radius: 8px; /*some css3*/
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-moz-transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
color: #005E20;
}
#nav ul li {
width:180px;
}
#nav ul li a {
background:transparent;
height:20px;
line-height:20px;
width:160px;
}
#nav:hover {
height:200px;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
-moz-transform:translate(0,161px); /*some css3*/
-o-transform:translate(0,161px);
-webkit-transform:translate(0,161px);
}
#nav a:hover,#nav li:hover > a {
color:#99ff33;
}
```

Comment: This screams for a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: If your plan is to learn to code I suggest you start again and take small steps, get it to work then move on. Build your navigation then add basic css to style. build the rest of you page and add basic css, preferably just blocks of color. Once you get that to look how you want it add the transforms. You are giving fixed positions then over riding with relative positions. Its confusing and messy.

Answer (score 0):

This changes the height of the nav on hover (pushing the rest of the page down):

```
#nav:hover {
    height:200px;
}
```

This changes the color to green on hover:

```
#nav a:hover, #nav li:hover > a {
    color:#99ff33;
}
```

Here's a rudimentary example without those hover definitions:
http://jsfiddle.net/w4uyX/

Answer (score 0):

It's all in your CSS code (which seems a bit unorganized to me).

To deal with the menu pushing other content down, please find the selector `#nav:hover` where a larger height is set.

Then find the selector `#nav a:hover,#nav li:hover > a`. There is the setting for the different color, when you hover over the menu.

Answer (score 0):

see my navbar and see the difference
http://codepen.io/leandroruel/pen/yrwKI